# Mongoose update returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I update a field with new properties that is initially set to be an empty object?

For example, I have the following schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

var RunSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    runId: { type: String },
    reports: {
      cookieSummary: {
        name: String,
        path: String
      }
    }
  }
)

export default mongoose.model('Run', RunSchema);
```

And I'm trying to update the following document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a0565c2537e0b5d9d08ee6b"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "reports": {},
    "runId": "8r4LNN3fRqd3qNgdW"
}
```

But when I run this code, it returns `undefined`:

```
  Run.findOneAndUpdate({runId: '8r4LNN3fRqd3qNgdW'}, 
  {
    $set: {'reports.cookieSummary': { 'name': 'test' }},
  }, (err, doc) => { console.log(doc) })
```

---

The `object` notation works after adding `type` to fields, like this: `name: { type: String }`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ***dot notation***, as you're setting just one field:

```
  Run.findOneAndUpdate(
   { runId: '8r4LNN3fRqd3qNgdW' }, 
   { $set: {'reports.cookieSummary.name': 'test' } },
   (err, doc) => { console.log(doc) })
```

[According to the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/), the command you're using should work but you write it wrongly. Try like this:

```
 Run.findOneAndUpdate(
  { runId: '8r4LNN3fRqd3qNgdW' }, 
  { $set: { 'reports.cookieSummary': {'name': 'test'} } },
  (err, doc) => { console.log(doc) })
```

if it does not work, maybe mongo expect that the object matches its schema when you use the command like this. But I don't think so.

Let me know.

Comment: This works, but what if I need to add 10 properties to the `cookieSummary` object?  Do I have an other option, or this is the single solution which means that I should use the same approach for all of them?

Comment: The second solution returns an error on `reports.cookieSummary`: `Unexpected token, expected , `

Comment: Tried, still `undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158692/discussion-between-elmer-dantas-and-valip).

Answer (score 0):

Your query for update a document is good only the mistake is at the end of curly braces of $set. You entered un-necessary comma at the end that is actually creating problem in this case. So I suggest you to remove it and run this :

```
Run.findOneAndUpdate({runId: '8r4LNN3fRqd3qNgdW'}, 
{
$set: {'reports.cookieSummary': { 'name': 'test' }}
}, (err, doc) => { console.log(doc) });
```

and then see. Rest of your query is fine.

Hope It will work for you.
Thanks.

Comment: Tried it and I'm still getting `undefined`

Comment: Can you please send here your query if possible.

And please one time use this:

    Run.findOneAndUpdate({runId: '8r4LNN3fRqd3qNgdW'}, 
{
$set: {'reports.cookieSummary': { 'name': 'test' }}
}).exec((err, doc) => { console.log(doc) });



Use exec() function

Comment: I tried using the exec() function and it returns `null`

Comment: @Valip I think you are still missing something. Query that I told you is fine. Please send your query.


And please make sure you have entry in DB also correspond to this runID.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code, it will update the document and return the updated document.

```
var Q = require('q');

var deferred = Q.defer();
Run.findOneAndUpdate({ runId: '8r4LNN3fRqd3qNgdW' }, { $set: { 'reports.cookieSummary.name': 'test' } }, { new: true },
    (err, doc) => {
        console.log(doc);
        deferred.resolve(doc);
    });
return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: it returns `null`

Comment: @valip - I have edited my answer according to your need.Since findOneAndUpdate  is an asynchronous function , it was returning null even before executing the function. Above code makes use of 'q' promise library, which will return the result only after executing the findOneAndUpdate function..

Comment: this is exactly what I already answered. The dot notation is working but passing an entire object `{ 'reports.cookieSummary': {'name': 'test'}`, for some reason is not.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small change. Test this solution.

```
    Run.findOneAndUpdate({runId: '8r4LNN3fRqd3qNgdW'}, 
    {
        $set: {"reports": {'cookieSummary':{'name': 'test'}}},
    }, (err, doc) => { console.log(doc) })
```